# matplotlib pyplot does not plot in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, canopy

I am using VS 2013 Express version with python tools and canopy installed (python 2.7).

I am trying to plot a simple function when I run the code and it doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

plt.plot(np.random.rand(1000).cumsum())
```

I'm using interactive mode as IPython and when I execute the above in the command prompt, I see the plot.

The only difference between this plot on the cmd and in VS 2013 is the --pylab option I use when I load IPython on the commands prompt. When I tries to add --pylab and an Interpreter Options (Tools --> Setting --> Python Tools --> Interactive Windows).

anyone knows how I can get actual matplotlib plots when I run my python code on Visual Studio ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to type `plt.show()`

pylab mode makes this unnecessary.

http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related